# Firebird WHERE clause in selecting fields

Tags: select, firebird, where-clause

I Have here firebird query and I dont think if this is correct.

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(STATUS) FROM(SELECT STATUS FROM T_TABLE2 WHERE STATUS = 'FAIL') AS FAIL,  
      DEVICENAME,  
      SITE_NUM,  
      COUNT(TEST_NUM)  
FROM T_TABLE2 A  
INNER JOIN T_TABLE1 B  
ON A.TBL1_ID = B.ID  
WHERE B.DEVICENAME = 'TANM1A009A_P28'  
AND A.TEST_NUM = 'T810'  
GROUP BY 
      DEVICENAME, 
      TESTER, 
      SITE_NUM
```

I want to count the row of **TEST_NUM** even if it has FAIL value and I also want to count the **STATUS** that has FAIL value. 
Thanks

Comment: what's the problem here?

Comment: is this line correct ? COUNT(STATUS) FROM(SELECT STATUS FROM T_TABLE2 WHERE STATUS = 'FAIL') AS FAIL,

Comment: im not that familiar in firebird, but in SQLServer, that isnt Correct, it should be  
`COUNT(STATUS) AS FAIL FROM (SELECT STATUS FROM T_TABLE2 WHERE STATUS = 'FAIL')`

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know FireBird but from MSSQL point of view why don'y you try this??

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(A.STATUS) as 'FAIL', 
      B.DEVICENAME, 
      (TableofYourSitenum)SITE_NUM, -- i do no know what table this from 
      (TableofYourTestnum)COUNT(TEST_NUM)  as 'TESTNUM COUNT' --and this also you need to put the table name,
FROM T_TABLE2 A  
INNER JOIN T_TABLE1 B  
ON A.TBL1_ID = B.ID  
WHERE B.DEVICENAME = 'TANM1A009A_P28'  
AND A.TEST_NUM = 'T810'  
GROUP BY 
      A.STATUS, 
      (TableofYourTestnum)TESTNUM
```